# Counting number of executions in a recursive fibonacci method

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

I am trying to implement a count variable 'e' that stores the number of times the recursive function below has executed, but I am getting an error as below. I would sincerely appreciate an explanation of the concept as I also tried declaring the variable above the function to no avail. Also, alternative solutions are welcome.

```
def fibonacci(n, e):
    e[0] += 1
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fibonacci(n-1, e) + fibonacci(n-2, e), e


given_index = 8
count = [0]
result = fibonacci(given_index, count)
print("Traditional recursive Fibonacci sequence solution:", result, "Execution:", result)
```

Output:

```
   TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

---

**Updated answer with alternate implementation:**

I was able to implement this functionality in an alternate way. I am leaving it here for reference.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    global calculations
    calculations += 1
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

given_index = 8
global calculations
calculations = 0
print("Traditional recursive Fibonacci sequence solution:", fibonacci(given_index), "Executions:", calculations)
```

Comment: Your function sometimes returns and `int` and sometimes a `tuple`. Pick one and stick with it

Comment: Python is trying to *concatenate* rather than the intended addition, given the final return type is a tuple.

Comment: No need to return `e` anywhere if it's still the same reference that you already have. Return value type does not need to match input arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
return fibonacci(n-1, e)[0] + fibonacci(n-2, e)[0], e
```

You are returning a tuple and you are adding them together like integers. You can change by indexing the first values as to avoid the tuples and get the value itself.

Can also do the same

```
result, count = fibonacci(given_index, count)
```

Also others raise valid points in different ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
> occurs when we try to concatenate a tuple and an integer . Here when you are returning `fibonacci(n-1, e) + fibonacci(n-2, e), e` for n<=2 `fibonacci()` will return an integer and e is a tuple so when you go deep in the recursion it would give this error, better to remove the e and just return `fibonacci(n-1, e) + fibonacci(n-2, e)`